# How to display only users that can't login and eliminate the rest in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns and data and I'm trying to write a query so it only displays when a user hasn't logged in:

```
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'password reset' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'logged in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Kevin' as First_name, 'Owens' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Kevin' as First_name, 'Owens' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Kevin' as First_name, 'Owens' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all                   
SELECT 'Kevin' as First_name, 'Owens' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'password reset' as verb
union all                   
SELECT 'Kevin' as First_name, 'Owens' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'logged in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Kevin' as First_name, 'Owens' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'logged in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Roman' as First_name, 'Reigns' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all                   
SELECT 'Roman' as First_name, 'Reigns' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all                   
SELECT 'Roman' as First_name, 'Reigns' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Roman' as First_name, 'Reigns' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all                   
SELECT 'Roman' as First_name, 'Reigns' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'password reset' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Roman' as First_name, 'Reigns' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'password reset' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'password reset' as verb
union all
SELECT 'Seth' as First_name, 'Rollins' as Last_Name, getdate() as timestamp, 'tried log in' as verb
```

This gives me the following output:

```
First_name  Last_Name   timestamp              verb
Seth        Rollins 2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Seth        Rollins 2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Seth        Rollins 2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 password reset
Seth        Rollins 2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 logged in
Kevin       Owens   2017-02-19 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Kevin       Owens   2017-02-19 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Kevin       Owens   2017-02-19 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Kevin       Owens   2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 password reset
Kevin       Owens   2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 logged in
Kevin       Owens   2017-02-21 15:28:55.660 logged in
Roman       Reigns  2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Roman       Reigns  2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Roman       Reigns  2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Roman       Reigns  2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Roman       Reigns  2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 password reset
Roman       Reigns  2017-02-20 15:28:55.660 password reset
Seth        Rollins 2017-02-21 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Seth        Rollins 2017-02-21 15:28:55.660 tried log in
Seth        Rollins 2017-02-21 15:28:55.660 tried log in
```

I'm currently trying to write a query so it only displays the counts of Roman  Reigns as he hasn't logged in successfully so it would show the count of how many times he's tried to login as well as password resets. The first set of results for Seth Rollins should not be displayed but the ones from 21-02-2017 should be displayed as he hasn't successfully logged in.

I'm currently trying to work out the best method to write this query.

My expected outcome would be the following:

```
First_Name, Last_Name, Count of TriedLogIn, Count of PasswordResets
Roman        Reigns            4                        2
Seth         Rollins           3                       null
```

The reason why Seth Rollins name has appeared is because after successfully logging in on the 20/02 he hasn't had a successfully login since that date (21/02). After successfully logging in the count is then reset back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

For that specific user, use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select count(case when verb = 'tried log in' then 1 end) as loginfailures,
       count(case when verb = 'password reset' then 1 end) as passwordresets
from tablename
where First_name = 'Roman' and Last_name = 'Reigns'
```

If you want the same info, but for all users, do a `GROUP BY`:

```
select First_name, Last_name,
       count(case when verb = 'tried log in' then 1 end) as loginfailures,
       count(case when verb = 'password reset' then 1 end) as passwordresets
from tablename
group by First_name, Last_name
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I guess this query wouldn't work as Seth Rollins was able to login the first time round after resetting his password but ran into difficulty a day later. In the code you've mentioned it would mean that both tried login and password reset from the 20/02/2017 would also be counted part of the counts.

Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: @VGJ, can you edit your question and add the expected result (as formatted text)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `not exists`

```
select *
from users u1
where verb = 'tried log in'
and not exists
(
select 1
from users u2
where u1.firstname = u2.firstname 
and u1.lastname = u2.lastname
and u2.verb = 'logged in'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but this query wouldn't work as expected - I've included the expected result in the question too.